# Task List delegate task to the user

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, tasks, task-list

Hi I have got a difficult question.

I have got a Task List with the some Task.

Only One person, or group should can create a Task.

The User which take a task Should Could edit a task, not delete a task.

Any who take a Task should can edit this task, but not more a task. Please help me how to do this on Task List.

Comment: Use Event Receiver on Task List, on ItemDeleting, ItemAdding, ItemUpdating check your conditions.. Return the response with Error!

Comment: Hi Arsalan Adam Khari, but where are Event Receiver in Sharepoint? Must I do it Programically? Thanks for replay.

Comment: [Creating SharePoint 2010 Event Receivers in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010(v=office.14).aspx), this should help